# which configuration file is in use?

Tags: .net, powershell, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

**Is it possible to determine the current cluster's ClusterConfigFilePath?**

With the service fabric cluster manager, I've created a 1 node cluster:

[image]

I would like to remove the cluster using powershell:

```
.\RemoveServiceFabricCluster.ps1 -ClusterConfigFilePath .\ClusterConfig.json -Force
# Removes Service Fabric from the current machine
.\CleanFabric.ps1
```

**How do I find out the path for ClusterConfigFilePath?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you download the standalone Service Fabric package, a few samples of the ClusterConfig.JSON file are downloaded to your work machine.

[image]

You can read more about config files [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-manifest).

Comment: so how do i know which config is in use? let's say i sit down at  a computer i've never used before, how do i know which config file is being used for the cluster?

Comment: Apparently the manifest is the config file you cluster uses. Just check http://localhost:19080/Explorer/index.html#/tab/manifest

Comment: ok but how do i know which config file to use when removing a cluster .\RemoveServiceFabricCluster.ps1 -ClusterConfigFilePath .\ClusterConfig.json -Force